# Matlab: Calculating the pairwise distance for a multidimensional cell array

Tags: matlab, logic, intersection, cell-array

I have a multidimensional cell array `attributes` (763x6 cell).**attributes:** [image: input]

I have no syntax errors. The distance matrix `D` that results from my code have the same values for each row. I don't know how to  my distance function to be able to handle multiple rows / instances.

### D:

[image: D]

Sample of my data 5x6 cell:

```
'low back pain risk factor staff'   'low back pain' 'low back pain risk factor staff'   'back pain pain risk factor epidemiology' 'spiritual comment comment care be' 'spiritual comment comment care be'
'psd psd antipsychotic essential receptor'  'ht ht 5'   'antipsychotic protein signal receptor drug'    'cell protein signal cell receptor' 'spiritual comment comment care be' 'spiritual comment comment care be'
'school of medicine'    'case western reserve university'   'antidepressant action 5 for in'    'ht ht 5' 'spiritual comment comment care be' 'spiritual comment comment care be'
'spiritual comment comment care be' 'heal holistic comment india india' 'heal religious mental disorder psychiatric symptom'    'heal religious mental disorder psychiatric psychiatric' 'spiritual comment comment care be' 'spiritual comment comment care be'
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data that we can test the code on?

Comment: Unfortunately, No. The data that I'm working on have copy rights and I'm not allowed to share it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the _real_ data, just _some_ data that has the shape and properties of your data. If it was numbers I would already generate some random data, but with strings it's more efficient to have some small data that resemble the true data (either buy sample or invented one)

Comment: I've edited my question with adding a sample data 5X6 cell

Comment: Can you explain why you're using `pdist2` instead of `pdist`? Since the contents of each row of the original data are of variable length and in a cell array, and you're doing a comparison based on each cell but want an overall row-to-row distance, `pdist` seems like the more natural choice.  And your function is already returning the appropriate form of answer for `pdist` (but not `pdist2`)

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I think you want to just change your function call to `D = pdist(X,@intersection);`

Comment: I need pdist2 because I'm dealing with dbscan clustering which needs pdist2

Comment: Why did you delete the code that is the subject of your question from the question?

Comment: What do you mean by pair-wise distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution, but is too long to fit in as a comment. The problem is in how `pdist2` is calculating the pair-wise distances.

To quickly check this we can pass it a distance function which just prints out the `XI` and `XJ` arguments passed to it (when it is called from `pdist2`):

```
X = {'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5', 'foo6';...
     'bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3', 'bar4', 'bar5', 'bar6'};

% call distance function via pdist2
D = pdist2(X,X,@printArgsIn);
```

And in a function file:

```
function D2 = printArgsIn(XI,XJ)
    disp('XI'); disp(XI);
    disp('XJ'); disp(XJ);

    D2 = 1;
end
```

This returns the following:

```
XI
    'foo1'    'foo2'    'foo3'    'foo4'    'foo5'    'foo6'

XJ
    'foo1'    'foo2'    'foo3'    'foo4'    'foo5'    'foo6'

XI
    'foo1'    'foo2'    'foo3'    'foo4'    'foo5'    'foo6'

XJ
    'foo1'    'foo2'    'foo3'    'foo4'    'foo5'    'foo6'
    'bar1'    'bar2'    'bar3'    'bar4'    'bar5'    'bar6'

XI
    'bar1'    'bar2'    'bar3'    'bar4'    'bar5'    'bar6'

XJ
    'foo1'    'foo2'    'foo3'    'foo4'    'foo5'    'foo6'
    'bar1'    'bar2'    'bar3'    'bar4'    'bar5'    'bar6'
```

Ignoring the first `XI, XJ` pair (if you look at pdist2 in detail you'll see distance function is called once to test it works), you can see that it calls the distance function on observation 1 of `XI` against all observations of `XJ`.

In other words it expects your distance function to be able to handle multiple rows/instances, and return a column vector of distances. I haven't looked at your distance function in detail, but I don't think you are allowing for this.

Comment: If I understand your distance function correctly, it expects to receive two arguments, each of which is a single row of the cell array, and it returns `D2` a single distance. Instead it's second argument will be several rows, and it needs to return a column of distances, one distance for each row in the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your distance function, which needs to be able to return multiple distances when given multiple rows in the second argument, as detailed in the table in the [`pdist2` documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html).

It also seems to be handling the cell arrays generated by `regexp` wrong. By using `cellfun` to pass cell arrays of words to `intersect`, the `intersect` function is being asked to compare the letters in different words.

I believe the following function returns values with the desired effect:

```
function D2 = intersection(XI,XJ)

wordsI = regexp(XI, '\s+', 'split');
wordsJ = regexp(XJ, '\s+', 'split');

D2 = zeros(size(XJ,1),1);
for i=1:numel(D2)
    D2(i) = sum(cellfun(@(wI,wJ) numel(intersect(wI,wJ)), wordsI, wordsJ(i,:)));
end
```